# How do I set an image in front of the banner?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a banner that is fixed on the bottom of my website. I wanted to add a picture of a book on the top of the banner. So I placed the image in a div outside of the `fixed-footer-wrapper`, called `.fixed-footer-wrapper2`. Everything is fine, except the book is still behind the banner. I need the book in front of the banner. I tried z-index but it did not place the image in front. So how do I get the image to be in front?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/3gz7wk4m/

```
.fixed-footer-wrapper2 {
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 16px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-bottom: -50px;
display: -ms-flexbox;
position: fixed;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `.fixed-footer-wrapper` to `z-index: -1;` should work. That will set that class below everything else in terms of positioning.

Example:

```
.fixed-footer-wrapper {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Now your image is transparent so that might make it look a bit strange but that should work.

Comment: That image was just a placeholder, but it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add z-index:-1 on .fixed-footer-wrapper to bring it back. z-index works only on block elements such as divs; not on images. Here I have the updated code for .fixed-footer-wrapper. Hope that helps!

```
.fixed-footer-wrapper {
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      padding-top: 16px;
      padding-bottom: 16px;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      position: fixed;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      background-color: rgba(91, 172, 220, 0.95);
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      z-index:-1; 
}
```

Comment: I Appreciate the lesson...I didn't know z-index did not work on images

Comment: @GeorGios, it will work on image if you set its `position` property to some value other than `static`.